# Split Varchar String in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, varchar

I have the following values in a certain column ("Column A") in MySQL (using Sequel Pro):

```
ALE37183
ALE37184
ALE37185
BLW33814
BLW33815
```

etc.

They are `varchar`.

Is there a way to split those strings so that I get two separate columns:

```
Column A    Column B
ALE         37183
ALE         37184
ALE         37185
BLW         33814
BLW         33815
```

or even get rid of the ALE/BLW altogether and leave me with just the 37183, 37184, etc.?

Basically a reverse concatenate.

Thanks!

Comment: if the chars are always 3 you could use SUBSTRING

Comment: Aha! Didn't know that existed. Thank you, I'll try it out.

Comment: if it solves your problem - feel free to add it as an "answer" so that others with the same problem can find a solution to their problems too :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

If the count of chars and digths is same you could use it.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(yourcolumn, 1,3) AS ColumnA, SUBSTRING(yourcolumn, 4, 5) AS ColumnB 
 FROM your_table
```